# Visual Studio watch memory consumption

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Is is possible to watch the memory consumed in a given point of the application in Visual Studio 2008 and monitor its evolution in a simple way?

Answer (score 1):

[VMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533.aspx) from SysInternals shows quite a few details along the lines of what you might be looking for.